# Syntax error near  rank() function

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax-error, window-functions

I wrote an SQL query that need to be rewritten.
Basically, it does something like this :

```
select log_number, 
    code_id, 
    code_name, 
    ... 
    buyer_id,
    ...
    rank() over (
        partition by code_id, buyer_id 
        order by (date_trunc('second',cdr.dateconso) - date_trunc('second',log.datecrea)) asc
        ) as ranking,
from ...
join ... on ...
left join ... on ...
join ...
where ...
```

And it works perfectly with the last version of PostgreSQL.

But, the following instruction :

```
rank() over (
    partition by code.blg_promocode_keyid, cdr.tph_wp_account_buyer_keyid 
    order by (date_trunc('second',cdr.dateconso) - date_trunc('second',log.datecrea)) asc
    ) as ranking,
```

... generates a syntax error with current installed PostgreSQL version and I have to find a solution to bypass it but I have no clue.

> Error :  Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "over" LINE 21:
>   rank() over (partition by ...

Comment: and "current installed postgreSQL" is? If it's 8.3 or older, there's no support for window functions, you need 8.4 or newer for that. Otherwise, please show the whole un-edited SQL statement, as the syntax error is likely earlier.

Comment: You write about "last version of PostgreSQL" and still keep the versions in play a secret? Are you mocking us?

Comment: I wrote and run my query on a pg 9.0 while the other machine runs a 8.2 which does not support the window function. 

Sorry for giving you this information with a delay.

Comment: 8.2 is out of support. You should really upgrade that machine to a current verision.

Comment: Totally agreed even if I can't do that as it's not *my* job to upgrade postgres (but i definitely asked for it !)

Answer (score 1):

#### It might be trivial ..

```
select log_number,
   ...
   rank() over (
        partition by code_id, buyer_id 
        order by (date_trunc('second',cdr.dateconso)
                - date_trunc('second',log.datecrea))
        ) as ranking,
from ...
```

.. if you in fact have a **comma** after the last `SELECT` item (which you shouldn't).

#### .. or not

As clarified in a later comment, the objective is to **emulate [`rank()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) in an old version of PostgreSQL** without window functions - version 8.2 or older.

What you *really* should do is upgrade to a more recent version that features window functions (PostgreSQL 8.4 or later). [PostgreSQL 8.2 has reached end-of-life in Dec.2011](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/).

Barring that, you can emulate `rank()` with the help of a *temporary sequence*, a *temporary table*, some *subqueries* and *aggregate functions* in PostgreSQL 8.2. But it's not pretty:

**Test setup** (simplified from your example)

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t(code_id int, buyer_id int, the_date date);
INSERT INTO t  VALUES
 (1, 1, '2012-08-01')
,(1, 1, '2012-08-01')
,(1, 1, '2012-08-01')
,(1, 1, '2012-08-02')
,(1, 1, '2012-08-03')
,(1, 1, '2012-08-04')
,(2, 3, '2012-09-01')
,(2, 3, '2012-09-02')
,(2, 3, '2012-09-02')
,(2, 3, '2012-09-02')
,(2, 3, '2012-09-04')
,(2, 3, '2012-09-06');
```

I use a *temporary table* to reuse the results multiple times. In modern day PostgreSQL you'd use a CTE instead.
The *temporary sequence* serves as a poor man's substitute for `row_number()` in connection with [`nextval()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-sequence.html). To get a basic row number order by all columns that you would `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` for `rank()` - in that order:

```
CREATE TEMP SEQUENCE t_seq;  -- once per session ..
-- SELECT setval('t_seq', 1, FALSE); --  .. or reset for repeated use

-- DROP TABLE tmp; 
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp AS     -- once per session or drop first
SELECT code_id
      ,buyer_id
      ,the_date
      ,nextval('t_seq') AS rownum
       -- rank() included to compare results in modern version
       -- remove this line in old version:
      ,rank() OVER (PARTITION BY code_id, buyer_id ORDER BY the_date) AS rnk
FROM   t
ORDER  BY code_id, buyer_id, the_date;
```

You could also write a language `C` function like [Depesz demonstrates here](http://www.depesz.com/2007/08/17/rownum-anyone-cumulative-sum-in-one-query/) ...

Now, get the minimum `rownum` per peer-group (subquery `peer`) and subtract the minimum `rownum` per group (subquery `grp`) to arrive at actual row numbers:

```
SELECT t.*, peer.rn - grp.rn AS rnk_8_2
FROM   tmp t
JOIN (
   SELECT code_id, buyer_id, min(rownum) -1 AS rn
   FROM   tmp
   GROUP  BY code_id, buyer_id
   ) grp USING (code_id, buyer_id)
JOIN (
   SELECT code_id, buyer_id, the_date, min(rownum) AS rn
   FROM   tmp
   GROUP  BY code_id, buyer_id, the_date
   ) peer USING (code_id, buyer_id, the_date)
ORDER BY code_id, buyer_id, the_date;
```

Voilá. `rnk_8_2` matches `rnk`.

Clean up (or let objects be dropped at end of session):

```
DROP SEQUENCE t_seq;
DROP TABLE t, tmp;
```

Be aware that you have to create / reset / recreate temporary objects per session / execution.
Tested in PostgreSQL 9.1, but should work in 8.2.

Comment: Thank you. But actually I was asking about how to bypass the window function so the query can run on a 8.2 (even if it wasn't clear at all at first.)

Comment: @sabrina: What you are looking for is not trivial with the outdated version 8.2. I added a possible solution.

Comment: Thank you so much Erwin for this rank() emulation how-to. I'm gonna try it but I'll try to get the software upgraded anyway.